# Display: none and Flash video issue with FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash

I have an interesting issue.  I am using FancyBox lightbox to display a "video" tag when the user click on the image thumbnail, and it works great for all forms of HTML5 video. The main issue, is when testing in browsers older than IE9, the flash fallback does not load.

I am using the HTML5Media.info HTML5 video javascript plugin to automatically detect the "video" tag and create a flash fallback "object" if the browser does not recognize the "video" tag. This plugin can't be edited, because it is a linked file, not one that lives on my server.

I know the issue is with the "display: none;" that is one the surrounding DIV.

I know of the methods/fixes using

```
height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden;
```

But those won't work in my case.  Since the flash object/embed is being generated dynamically based on what browser the user has, and FancyBox relies on "display: none;" I can't use this. FancyBox is also being used in other places on the site and changing it to support this would be more work than is necessary.

I need a way with Javascript or jQuery to detect whether or not the display state of the surrounding DIV is set to none or not, and then, when the DIV is displayed, to THEN load the flash video.

Could this be done with an AJAX call?

Let me know if you know of a way to do this. Sorry, I'm getting better at Javascript, but I am not an expert by any means, so any help is appreciated!

I also apologize for not including a reference link, it's a company project. Non-disclosure stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 0; width:0; overflow: hidden;
```

This ended up working pretty nicely actually. I tried it before, and it didn't work properly. I don't know why, but for anyone using FancyBox, who is loading SWFs or FlashPlayers in dynamically, this is the css you want to hide the DIV with. Works like a charm. FancyBox automatically resizes the DIV to what it need to be.